# 25,42=90: find the math pattern

Tags: mathematics, pattern

I've got the following pattern:

```
25,42=90
62,31=92
73,12=?
```

What rule should I apply to 73 and 12 in order to get the answer? With brute force, the answer is

> 156

but the rule is not clear. It's level 74 from the [Math Puzzles & Brain Riddles Android game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6G5X.jpg)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what I think the rule is

> Write the second number as $CD$ with $C$ being the first digit, $D$ the second, then
>  $$a, CD = a \times D + 10C$$

In particular

> $25, 42 = 25 \times 2 + 40 = 90$
>  $62, 31 = 62 \times 1 + 30 = 92$
>  $73, 12 = 73 \times 2 + 10 = 156$

Note

> This was found after OP's comment stating they had found the answer through brute force.