# Unexpected answer to sequence riddle

Tags: riddle, mathematics

I've got the following sequence:

```
11+11=4
12+12=6
13+13=8
14+14=?
```

I've tried multiple approaches:

1. Assuming that the formula is `A + B - 18 = C` the answer should be `10`.
2. Assuming that we write the first number as `AB` and the second one as `CD`, and the formula is `A+B+C+D`, the answer should be again `10`.
3. Assuming that we just increment the right part of equation by `2` in each row the answer should again be `10`.

But the answer is `1`.

Could one explain the rule behind this riddle?

P.S. This is level 55 of [this game](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121411/puzzling-sequence).

Comment: These kind of puzzles often turn into 'guess what the puzzle creator had in mind'. Above a certain complexity it becomes a subjective choice which explanation is easier or more obvious. For this particular example I think 10 is a much more obvious answer. Given the creator wants the answer 1 one can think of definitions to arrive there. Similarly one could come up with reasonable formulas for a lot of other possible answers.

Comment: @quarague I totally agree. Personally I don't understand why the authors don't show the formula but the plain true/false for an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks to me like you have to

> sum the digits in each equation until you end up with a single digit:
>
>  1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 4
>  1 + 2 + 1 + 2 = 6
>  1 + 3 + 1 + 3 = 8
>  1 + 4 + 1 + 4 = 10 - but wait! We need to sum the digits again: 1 + 0 = 1

This is technically the same as [fljx's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121443/unexpected-answer-to-sequence-riddle/121444#121444) but feels a bit more puzzly to me.

Comment: Or the answer is just truncated to the first digit. The inputbox had unfortunately a max length of 1 :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, the problem is that the riddle doesn't reveal its logics, it just tells whether the answer is correct or not.

Answer (score 5):

One possible explanation is:

> They are all regular sums, but the answers are all mod 9.
>
>  11+11 = 22 = 4 mod 9
>  12+12 = 24 = 6 mod 9
>  13+13 = 26 = 8 mod 9
>  14+14 = 28 = 1 mod 9

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, the problem is that the riddle doesn't reveal its logics, it just tells whether the answer is correct or not.

Comment: pay attention, that `12+12 = 24`, not `22`

Comment: The second 22 was a simple typo. The answer is still valid.